# Adjust height of adjacent container

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and I'm currently trying to create a simple container layout which consists of a header container that is filled with 3 smaller container. The container are filled with images and when the width of the page gets too small, the image in the center container start shrinking, which is exactly what I want. Now the problem that I have is that I would like the entire header to shrink vertically but the other 2 container just stick to their size no matter what I try.

As an example, my total width for the header is 640px and the height is 128px

```
Left = 64x128
Center = Whatever is left between L and R
Right = 128x128
```

[Picture to visualize everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeaQI.jpg)

[How it looks when the width is changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wAlw.jpg)

What I would want it to be when the center is shrinking by e.g. 20px height:

```
Left = 64x108 (keeps its width but adjusts the height based on center)
Center = Still hatever is left between L and R
Right = 108x108 (adjusts both, width and height based on center height)
```

The center is filled with an image that fits perfectly and when there isn't enough space, it shrinks and keeps its aspect ratio which means it will always have a perfect fit horizontally but because L and R are not shrinking, it doesn't fit vertically anymore. How do I make it so that L and R are getting their height from the center?

My current code:

[index.html](https://pastebin.com/QiCSg9BM)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menubtn"></div>
                <div class="logo"></div>
                <div class="avatar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="main"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[style.css](https://pastebin.com/UEvTLEkW)

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.page {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 640px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header {
    border: 2px solid green;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 128px;
}

.menubtn {
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 64px;
    height: 128px;
}

.logo {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 64px;
    right: 128px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.logo img {
    width: 100%;
}

.avatar {
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
}

.avatar img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Please ignore how messy it looks, I removed tons of unrelated stuff to make everything shorter and a lot of things are leftover or shouldn't be there in the first place haha

Is something like that possible with just CSS, or would that require scripting?

Comment: Please edit you post to include a [mre]. Links to other websites are fine, but they must be accompanied by a code block in your post.

Comment: @Rojo Done, sorry. I thought it would make it cleaner and easier to read if I add them as external links.

Comment: That's alright! Just make sure to read [ask] and [mre] before posting a question to get the best answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wanna like this?

```css
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .page {
      border: 2px solid blue;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 640px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 80%;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .header {
      border: 2px solid green;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 640px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: stretch;
    }

    .menubtn {
      border: 2px solid red;
      width: 64px;
      min-width: 64px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    .menubtn img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    .logo {
      border: 2px solid yellow;
      width: auto;
      min-width: 60%;
      min-height: min-content;
    }

    .logo img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    .avatar {
      border: 2px solid black;
      padding: 4px;
    }

    .avatar img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="menubtn">
        <img
          src="data:image/png;base64,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"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="avatar">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8cmFuZG9tfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80"></img>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Almost. I tried a direct copy of your code (used my images to see the result) and after some small changes, it is very close to what I want with a small problem. I removed padding from .avatar and added max-width 128px to .avatar, after that, eveything looks perfect. The problem is that when I start to shrink the browser width, at first it starts to shrink the center container horizontally while the left and right side of the image start hiding behind the other 2 container. After a while, everything starts to shrink at the exact same rate the way I want it to. Its basically 99% there haha

Comment: Okay the problem is fixed and everything is awesome now. The problem to the comment above was the min-width that was set to 60%. I changed it to 70% (640px -64 -128) and now everything is shrinking absolutely perfect. Thank you for your help @TBT you made my day!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).